React Chart.js is not rendering lines when state changes
I am using React Chart.js V2 and I am trying to update my chart when the state changes. However it is only rendering the y-labels on the left side and is not drawing the lines. The dataset and label syntax is completely fine (see the image). If i take the console logged result and take it as the initial chart js state value it works fine, but still doesn't update on state change.

This is my code:
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

const chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Multi Axis',
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        maxTicksLimit: 6
      }
    }
  }
};

export default function Home({ ranking }) {
  const refreshChart() => {
    ...
    console.log({
      datasets,
      labels: dateLabels
    })
    setChartData({
      datasets,
      labels: dateLabels
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!statisticsLoading)
      refreshChart()
  }, [statisticsTimeSpan, statisticsLoading])


    return (
        ...
        <Line
            className="mb-4"
            options={chartOptions}
            data={chartData}
            redraw
        />
    )
}



Please provide the data as code snippet.

I have noticed that I provided the wrong format for the labels to react-chartjs-2...
For the "labels" property i provided an array inside an array which is wrong. It has to be only one array.
